# R - basic subsetting: keeping some variables of a larger data frame

Tags: r, variables, subset, paste

I'm learning the basics of R, and want to understand the underlying assumptions that the language makes in specific situations.

CORE QUESTIONS:
 1. Why does METHOD 2 below return an error?
 2. Why does METHOD 3 below alphabetize the variables?

In a data frame "data" with the following variables

```
Zeta    Alpha    Gamma    Delta    Sum    Mean    Corr
```

I'm trying to subset the variables "Zeta", "Delta", "Sum", "Mean", and "Corr".

"METHOD 1" (successful):

```
> newdata <- data[c(1, 4:7)]
```

"METHOD 2" (Error):

```
> myvars <- paste(data[c(1, 4:7)], sep="")
> newdata <- data[myvars]
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, myvars) : undefined columns selected
```

I think this is related to the fact that paste coerces values to characters, but I'm not clear on how that would affect the function.

"METHOD 3" (works, but alphabetizes output):

```
> myvars <- paste(ls(data[1, 4:7]), sep = "")
> newdata <- data[myvars]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to select a set of variable names from an R data.frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425194/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-select-a-set-of-variable-names-from-an-r-data)

Comment: @user2926101 That helps - thank you. But I restructured Q to explain what I'm actually getting at.

Comment: Do you have the following vector?  `data <- c('Zeta', 'Alpha', 'Gamma', 'Delta', 'Sum', 'Mean', 'Corr')`  If you have a data frame and are just providing the names of your variables, consider adding in sample data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting Method 2 to do. Run just `paste(data[c(1,4:7)], sep="")` to see what it's returning and why it's not working. Why not just do `data[c("Zeta", "Delta", "Sum", "Mean", "Corr")]`?

Comment: Using this as a sample. I could make that vector, but I intend to work with sets that have many, many variables. I'd like R to read them, rather than entering all of them.

Comment: Then why not just use method 1?

Comment: @user2926101 I know I know - I just want to understand what R is doing under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand why you're trying to use `paste()` here. This function is typically only for concatenating character values.

1. Method 2 returns an error because `paste(data[c(1, 4:7)], sep="")` returns `c("1", "4", "5", "6", "7")` which is a character vector and when you index with a character vector R looks up values by name rather than position and since there is no column named "1" or "4" in your data.frame, you get the error "undefined columns selected"
2. Method 3 alphabetizes the columns because `ls()` alphabetizes it's results. Just like your use of `paste`, this is a very bizarre use  of `ls()`. Typically this function is used to list all variables and function inside of a particular environment. Using them to extract column names probably isn't the best use.

So if your data looks like

```
data <- data.frame(Zeta=1, Alpha=2, Gamma=3, 
    Delta=4, Sum=5, Mean=6, Corr=7)
```

then a more usual way to get at the data is

```
myvars <- names(data)[c(1, 4:7)]
data[myvars]
```

Comment: excellent - thank you. I just got at the same data using myvars <- data[c(1, 4:7)]. Why did you use names()?

Comment: re: why paste - the internet told me to: http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html

Comment: @toandthrough I used names because with all the messing with `paste` and `ls` I thought you really wanted to index by column name rather than numerical index. Using `data[c(1, 4:7)]` is just fine. That use of `paste` on that link was for a very different purpose. They wanted columns "V1","V2", and "V3" but instead of typing them out, they used `paste("V", 1:3", sep="")` to generate that vector of names.

Comment: If your intent is to learn more about how R works, I'd recommend typing things like `paste("v", 1:3, sep="")` and `paste(data[c(1,4:7)], sep="")` in without using `<-` to see what R is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using column index. If your data changes or the columns get rearranged your code could break.

```
myvars <- c("Zeta", "Delta", "Sum", "Mean", "Corr")
newdata <- data[, myvars]
```

Or you could use `dplyr`:

```
newdata <- select(data, Zeta, Delta, Sum, Mean, Corr)
```