# Select multiple variables in r / rstudio to insert in a code

Tags: r, rstudio, add-in

I was wondering if there is a way to select multiple variables while writing a code. I mean when we type the dataframe name followed by $, we get the list of all variables but it only allows selecting one at a time.

Is there a way (like a package or rstudio add in) that allows selecting multiple?

what I have been doing so far is (and I got the ideas from this [2012 post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425194/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-select-a-set-of-variable-names-from-an-r-data)  ):

- use `dput(names(dataframe))` then select what I need
- use starts_with, ends_with, contains, etc... from dplyr (but these only work whenever there is a unique pattern to the variables of interest).

with all these nice rstudio add ins around, I was hoping there is a nicer/ more efficient way to select the variables without having to type them individually.

this sounds like a basic question and I apologize in advance if it has been asked before but I could not find an answer here or on stackoverflow.

thanks a lot

Comment: Are you looking for something graphical so that you don't need to type? Using `select()` from `dplyr` also allows a range. So you can do `df %>% select(col1:col10)` or something like that. From a second read, it seems like you are talking about the auto complete in RStudio, and how basically you'd want multiselect or checkboxes in that?

Answer (score 3):

None of the solutions below are specific to R Studio but are general facilities in R or dplyr.

There must be some way to select them so if there is no common pattern you can list them explicitly or use their positions.  Then any of these will select the columns -- in this example `mpg` and `cyl` columns from `mtcars`:

```
nms <- c("mpg", "cyl")
# or nms <- 1:2

mtcars[nms]
mtcars[, nms]
subset(mtcars, select = nms)
dplyr::select(mtcars, all_of(nms))
```

or if you want to specify a content related query use one of these:

```
iris[ sapply(iris, is.numeric) ]

dplyr::select(iris, where(is.numeric))
```

If what you mean is that you want a GUI to show the available names in a specific data frame so you can interactively select them then use this (see screenshot at end):

```
select.list(names(mtcars), multiple = TRUE)
```

or

```
library(tcltk)
tk_select.list(names(mtcars), multiple = TRUE)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks for your help. and yes I am looking for a GUI option. I don't know why rstudio did not include this `tk_select.list` to show up once we place the $ after the dataframe name!

Comment: `tk_select.list` does require that you load tcltk, i.e. `library(tcltk)`, but tcltk is a base package that comes with R so you don't have to install it if you use any of the common R distributions.   If you built your own R installation then you would have to be sure that tcl/tk was present when you built it.  It cannot be added afterwards if you built R without it.  Look at `capabilities()` to see if your installation has tcltk capability.

Comment: `tcltk` works for me. I just meant that it will be nicer if the menu that shows up after `$' in rstudio allows multiple selections (not only one at a time). few years ago I used something called deducer which was a java based r gui, this one had an excellent variable selection interface. I just feel efficient variable selection will save some time during code writing and will be less prone to typing errors.

Comment: Even apart from R Studio $ can never specify multiple values so that is likely why you don't get that.

Comment: I get it, but was wondering if there are add in or something with similar capability. I will leave the question open just in case someone is more informed about these kind of issues. thank you.